# Hibernate and too many connections

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on web-project with Hibernate ans Spring MVC.
My hibernate configuration is:

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/xxx</property>
<property name="connection.username">xxx</property>
<property name="connection.password">xxx</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>\<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
<property name="connection.useUnicode">true</property> 
<property name="connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property> 
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

The hibernate sessions are closing in service-classes destructors (these service-classes have DAO objects). But after publishing at production server I've got too many connections exception from mysql.Every server call, the mysql connection was opened. When the connections amount become 101 - db failed. I think that destructors had not time enought for executes so the connections were opened all the time.
Then, I rebuilded the structure. Now, the Spring controllers call the service-class function, that releases the session mannualy. But it doesn't help: the connections are still opened and now I can not use LAZY-collections in views because the session already closed.
How can I solve that problem? What is the usual approach here?
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by 'hibernate sessions are closing in service-classes destructors'?

Comment: That \ on line 7 between 2 properties.  Is that part of the *actual* XML, or a 'transcription to forum' error?